# string representation of list of dictionaries to list object of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, abstract-syntax-tree

I run a command over remctl using subprocess.check_output that returns a string as follows:

```
[{'key':'value', 'key':'value', 'Key':[{'key':'value'}]}, 
 {'key':'value', 'key':'value', 'Key':[{'key':'value'}]}]
```

How do I transform this into a object list of dictionaries so that Python can loop over it as usual?

I've tried `ast.literal_eval()` and got an error of `malformed string`. I also tried `json.loads()` and received `Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)` error.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: This is not a valid Python literal.

Comment: `'key','value'` should that be `'key':'value'`

Comment: Can you copy and paste the string into a .py file to see where the syntax error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Just print the first element of list, it will be the dictionary.

```
l = [{'key':'value', 'key','value', 'Key':[{'key':'value'}]}, 
 {'key':'value', 'key','value', 'Key':[{'key':'value'}]}]

d = l[0]

print(d)

# answer
{'key':'value', 'key','value', 'Key':[{'key':'value'}]}, 
 {'key':'value', 'key','value', 'Key':[{'key':'value'}]}
```

Comment: `l[0]` returns `[`. The output of subprocess.check_output is a string not a list.

Comment: what is the output of `type(l)`    assuming your subprocess.check_output is called l ?

Comment: `type(l)` returns `<type 'str'>`